# Why does repeatedly running a simple snippet generating pseudo-random numbers always yield the same results?

Tags: c++, random

Code:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <random>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

int nmax = 5;
long long amin = -10;
long long amax = 10;

int main()
{
    auto rand_ad = bind(uniform_int_distribution<long long>(amin, amax), default_random_engine(random_device{}()));
    ofstream out("testcase");

        out << nmax << ' ' << rand_ad() << '\n';
        for(int i = 0; i < nmax; i++) {
            out << rand_ad() << (i == nmax-1 ? '\n' : ' ');
        }

    return 0;
}
```

I run this code repeatedly. Whether I run it manually or by a script the results are always the same. When I inspect the contents of file `testcase`, it always contains:

```
5 -8
4 0 -1 3 -3
```

This perplexes me. To my best understanding, as soon as I write `default_random_engine(random_device{}())`, I do seed my pseudo-random engine!!, so the results should NOT be the same!

Even more, repeatedly calling this code (only ofstream replaced by cout) on Ideone gives different results: [link](https://ideone.com/xKd9vE)

If this matters, I'm on Windows, compiling with MinGW.

Is this:

- My misuse of C++;
- My PEBKAC wrt the installation of MinGW or calling the program;
- A Windows peculiarity?

Comment: Using `long long` seems like massive overkill for numbers in the range of -10 to 10. Also don't freak out, there's no need for repeated exclamations!!!

Comment: A simple pseudo-random but constant sequence of values is a legal but weak implementation of [`random_device`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/random_device). It's known to be used by MinGW.